# symfony ORM doctrine queries

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have easy query with inner join

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->innerJoin('UserBundle:User', 'u')
    ->where('r.nick = u.id')
    ->andWhere('r.odobera=:id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->orderBy('r.time', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(50);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

It should be one query right? But in profiler i have

```
SELECT t0.username AS [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1
Parameters: [1465] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 1.79 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT r0_.id AS id0, [...] FROM requests r0_ INNER [...] ORDER BY r0_.time DESC LIMIT 50
Parameters: [1465] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.67 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['2072'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.64 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['2386'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.50 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['79'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.50 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['2432'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.50 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['40'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.52 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['2090'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.46 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['1044'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.51 ms [   Explain query ]
 SELECT t0.username AS username1, [...] FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
Parameters: ['27'] 
[Display runnable query]
Time: 0.54 ms [   Explain query ]
```

one query for each "join" for each record... WHY?

PS: this text is just for making this post longer because i can't submit question with "just" so many details.. but i think my problem is explained very well. BTW: i asked friend and he has similiard problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what to select, so just `requests` where hydrated.

You can specify what to hydrate with `select()` method on the query builder:

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
     ->select(array('r', 'u'))
     ->innerJoin('UserBundle:User', 'u')
     ->where('r.nick = u.id')
     ->andWhere('r.odobera=:id')
     ->setParameter('id', $id)
     ->orderBy('r.time', 'DESC')
     ->setMaxResults(50);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: hm... it causing me problems ... didn't symfony guess select based on the relationship in entities? Because now the dump of the result looks nice.. requests object with property nick what is proxy to user entity... but when i add your part of code it looks weird and i cant then pass results to twig and access them like for follower in followers or something like that anymore...check screen: http://www.upnito.sk/0/5u5ztfusawxq5pk7uab7f3e49sr9h534.png

Comment: Symfony has nothing to do with it. It's a purely Doctrine thing. I updated my answer since initially I made a mistake on how you should specify fields you want to select.

Comment: I'm not sure what (and how) you're dumping. The code should produce correct result.

Comment: \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($followers);die();

Comment: I'm sure that `string` is here in place to prevent accidental recursions and I think that `Twig` should have not problem whatsoever with traversing the object. Have you tried running it? If it causes error which one is it?